# Report in ANCOVA: descriptive means or estimated marginal means?

Tags: ancova, bonferroni, reporting

I have conducted an analysis of covariance, ANCOVA, followed by Bonferroni post-hoc tests, on SPSS. I want to report the differences between my groups in text (APA style) and in a corresponding bar graph. My covariate (a different variable from the DV and IV, not a pretest) was found significant, so the descriptive means and the estimated marginal means (EMM) are different.

I want to know which of the means ("descriptive" or EMM) is better to report and put in the graph. One way to think about it is that the adjusted means are not real data but simply estimations from the software --nothing my article should be about. However my analysis will be drawn on the conclusions of the ANCOVA, comparing the EMM, so I should focus on the EMM.

I have explored various manuals and articles without finding a clear answer --I found everything and the opposite.

Should I graph the actual means as presented in the "descriptives" table, or should I graph the estimated marginal means?

Comment: Estimated marginal means are not only adjusted for the covariates; they are the predicted means with the collapsed subgroups _equally_ weighted. For example, consider you have two factors with groups A1 A2 B1 B2 and you want to know EMMs for B1 and B2 groups. Then EMM for B1 is the simple mean of 2 means of predicted values: mean(mean_predicted_value_in_A1B1, mean_predicted_value_in_A2B1).

Answer (score 1):

Report estimated marginal mean and standard error in writing results and making graph.